# CRON Job using Curl.

Tags: php, curl, cron

I have a PHP Code, which reloads itself with another `GET` value. Like: example.com?number=453 and it keeps doing this for days. I was doing this in the browser. But i found cron job is way better.

So, I need to use CURL to reload the page with a new GET value like `?number=550`. So this is the code, which i use (found it on stackoverflow)

```
function curl_download($Url){

    // is cURL installed yet?
    if (!function_exists('curl_init')){
        die('Sorry cURL is not installed!');
    }

    // OK cool - then let's create a new cURL resource handle
    $ch = curl_init();

    // Now set some options (most are optional)

    // Set URL to download
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $Url);

    // Set a referer
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://www.example.org/yay.htm");

    // User agent
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "MozillaXYZ/1.0");

    // Include header in result? (0 = yes, 1 = no)
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

    // Should cURL return or print out the data? (true = return, false = print)
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    // Timeout in seconds
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);

    // Download the given URL, and return output
    $output = curl_exec($ch);

    // Close the cURL resource, and free system resources
    curl_close($ch);

    return $output;
}


$output = curl_download("http://www.example.com/yourscript.php?number='$requestsDone'");
```

And at the end of the page, i use this, to call the function

```
curl_download($Url);
```

But i am getting this error:

> Notice: Undefined variable: Url

in the last line, i.e `curl_download($Url);`

This is how we call the function right? What's wrong? Also is there any mistake or improvement, I can make in the code?

Comment: Where is `$requestsDone` coming from? And it doesn't really need to be wrapped in single quotes.

Comment: It is coming from somewhere in the code bro. It is not an empty variable

Answer (score 1):

You not assign values ​​to variables $Url.
Before you can assign values ​​to variables $Url. That like

```
$Url = "http://domaintest.com/?number=550";
curl_download($Url);
```

Comment: It stopped the error. But it do not redirect my browser to the new URL. 

Do this code redirect browser?

Comment: Or it just work in the background? How do i know, if it is working?

Comment: Are you want open browser with this Url ?

Comment: No. I am just testing the code in my browser (instead of cron job). And it do nothing on browser.

Comment: and instead of this, can't i just put `curl_download($output);`?

Comment: can you change <pre>`$Url = "http://domaintest.com/?number=550";
    $output = curl_download($Url);
    var_dump($output);`</pre>

Comment: i got this `bool(false)`

Comment: The url fake . Not live.

Comment: it is real and live bro

Comment: Btw, I can even do this without opening different URL's...But i get time-out from the server (100 seconds);. If the PHP script takes more than 100 seconds to load. I will not get that when using this right?? 

Bcz i need to run this script for days